# Edit Strings in Android sent with Intent.ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, filter, share, root, xposed

my problem is that some apps have an option to share certain messages through messaging apps, for example I've seen plenty of games where if you reach a new high score you can share with it with your friends through an app like WhatsApp. However some of them like to add a nasty message at the bottom like "Download this app yourself at play.google.com/way/too/long/url/", and sometimes I have seen useless stuff like that making the message twice as long!

Now for the actual question, I'd like to know if I can filter that message automatically before it gets send. If I could intercept the message and read it line by line I could filter it by making a RegEx for it.

Some stuff to keep in mind: My device is rooted, and I plan on getting Xposed as soon as it becomes available for Nougat. I run CyanogenMod 14.1 based on Android 7.1.1 and I have barely any experience with making Android apps but I guess my general Java knowledge is average.

Comment: Certainly. The easiest method would probably be hooking the `ContextImpl.startActivity(Intent)` method and intercepting and modifying the intent contents (`intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)`) before the method is executed.

Comment: Could you specify a bit more on how to do this please? I don't know how I could hook the startActivity() method since I apps to send and receive the message are both not mine. It's kinda like a mitm thing.

Comment: Xposed allows you to inject your code into other apps. Simply follow the tutorial [here](https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial), but instead of hooking the clock, hook `ContextImpl.startActivity` instead.

Comment: Sounds interesting, but it'll have to wait then since Android 7 isn't supported yet by Xposed and I can't run a virtual machine.